# Javascript [virus?] added automatically on every page

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, virus

I don't know if this is any kind of virus, but lately i've been seeing stuff that i did not add to my browser, at first i thought thoses were code added to my webpages but now i see them on all webpages (including this one).

this is the javascript added:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="http://i.swebdpjs.info/opt_content.js?v=opt_1410177193622&amp;partner=sweb&amp;channel=sweb&amp;sset=2&amp;appTitle=&amp;sset=2&amp;ip=190.199.222.1"></script>
```

there are more added but this one is an example, i cannot tell which one are from `stackoverflow` but i recognize this one because it appears on every page.

i analyzed my pc with `nod32` and it does not find any virus threat and analyzed with `CCleaner`

any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think this is the proper forum for your question. SO is for coding specific questions. I'm going to flag for this to be moved to Super User where more general computing questions can be addressed.

Comment: Do you have any extensions/plugins enabled in your browser that might be adding this? Does it happen in all your browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser extensions and add-ons.  It's possible one of those is injecting this Javascript into every page.

Also try opening your browser in Incognito mode to see if it happens then.  Browser extensions and add-ons are disabled during incognito (or private browsing) mode.

It is also possible that your ISP is inserting this into every page.  In wich case we could do other things to stop this behavior.

Comment: it seems like it was an extension called `site advisor` but i never installed it, somehow it was installed.

Comment: Yes, site advisor is known for doing that.  You can safely disable it.  Did I answer your question?